# Subqueries inside While loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I need help please, I try to make a hierarchical organization php application, I then set up a database with the following structure :

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxDQK.jpg)

Basically, I have a list of the names of all employees.
The row of each employee contains, on successive columns (c5 to c10), the names of the services (descending hierarchy) from which he depends.
When I click on a particular employee name from the drop-down list, I send its "id" to a query that should return in a two-column table :

-1. in the second column, all services, hierarchically descending, from which the employee selected depends.
-2. in the first column, the managers of the various departements or services displayed in the first column.

To find the names of the services, for johana for example, the request is easy for me.

To find the names of the managers, for johana for example, I have to run 4 different requests for the service from which she depends :

-1. for marketing : query returning the person name in the field "name" for which the field "c5" contains "marketing" and the field "c6" is empty.
-2. for europe : query returning the person name in the field "name" for which field "c6" contains "europe" and field c7 is empty.
-3. for publicity : query returning the person name in the field "name" for which the field "c7" contains "publicity" and the field c8 is empty.
-4. for tv : publicity: query returning the person name in the field "name" for which the field "c8" contains "tv" and the field c9 is empty.

PS: For other needs, I inserted a column to indicate the column number of the last cell not empty, and another column to indicate the value of this cell.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
require_once '../config/dbconnect.php';
if(isset($_POST["prs_id"]) && !empty($_POST["prs_id"])){
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = ".$_POST['prs_id']."");
    $rowCount = $result->num_rows;
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            // utile variables -------------------
            $numcol = $row['lastcol'];
            $currcol = 'c' . $row['lastcol'];
            $currval = $row['lastval'];
            $prevcol = 'c' . ($row['lastcol'] - 1);
            $prevval = $row[$prevcol];
            $nextcol = 'c' . ($row['lastcol'] + 1);
            $nextval = $row[$nextcol];
            // -----------------------------------
            echo '<tr><td style="width:296px;">';
            echo 'query to find manager name level 1'; // returned value of query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c5 = $row['c5'] AND c6 = "" ");
            echo '</td><td>';
            echo $row['c5'];
            echo '</tr><tr><td>';
            echo 'query to find manager name level 2'; // returned value of query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c6 = $row['c6'] AND c7 = "" ");
            echo '</td><td>';
            echo $row['c6'];
            echo '</tr><tr><td>';
            echo 'query to find manager name level 3'; // returned value of query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c7 = $row['c7'] AND c8 = "" ");
            echo '</td><td>';
            echo $row['c7'];
            echo '</tr><tr><td>';
            echo 'query to find manager name level 4'; // returned value of query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c8 = $row['c8'] AND c9 = "" ");
            echo '</td><td>';
            echo $row['c8'];
            echo '</tr><tr><td>';
            echo 'query to find manager name level 5'; // returned value of query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c9 = $row['c9'] AND c9 = "" ");
            echo '</td><td>';
            echo $row['c9'];
            echo '</tr><tr><td>';
            echo 'employee name clicked in case his lastvalue is in c10';
            echo '</td><td>';
            echo $row['c10'];
            echo '</td></tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: Heard of sql injection?

Comment: What is you issue/question?

Comment: Hello everybody !

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem, so I post it for others :

```
<?php
require_once '../config/dbconnect.php';
if(!empty($_POST["prs_id"])) {
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['prs_id'])."'  ");
    $rowCount = $result->num_rows;
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $numcol = $row['lastcol'];
            $currcol = 'c' . $row['lastcol'];
            echo '<div>';
            if($currcol == 'c5'){
                echo '<tr><td>';
                $rsl5 = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c5 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c5'])."' AND c6 = '' ");
                $cnt5 = $rsl5->num_rows;
                while($rw5 = $rsl5->fetch_assoc()){
                    if($cnt5 == 1){
                        echo $rw5['name'];
                    } else {
                        echo $rw5['name'];
                        echo '<br />';
                    }
                }
                echo '</td><td>';
                echo $row['c5'];
                echo '</td></tr></table></div>';
            } else if($currcol == 'c10') {
                echo '<tr><td>';
                $rsl5 = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c5 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c5'])."' AND c6 = '' ");
                $cnt5 = $rsl5->num_rows;
                while($rw5 = $rsl5->fetch_assoc()){
                    if($cnt5 == 1){
                        echo $rw5['name'];
                    } else {
                        echo $rw5['name'];
                        echo '<br />';
                    }
                }
                echo '</td><td>';
                echo $row['c5'];
                echo '</td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>';
                $rsl6 = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c5 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c5'])."' AND c6 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c6'])."' AND c7 = '' ");
                $cnt6 = $rsl6->num_rows;
                while($rw6 = $rsl6->fetch_assoc()){
                    if($cnt6 == 1){
                        echo $rw6['name'];
                    } else {
                        echo $rw6['name'];
                        echo '<br />';
                    }
                }
                echo '</td><td>';
                echo $row['c6'];
                echo '</td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>';
                $rsl7 = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c6 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c6'])."' AND c7 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c7'])."' AND c8 = '' ");
                $cnt7 = $rsl7->num_rows;
                while($rw7 = $rsl7->fetch_assoc()){
                    if($cnt7 == 1){
                        echo $rw7['name'];
                    } else {
                        echo $rw7['name'];
                        echo '<br />';
                    }
                }
                echo '</td><td>';
                echo $row['c7'];
                echo '</td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>';
                $rsl8 = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c7 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c7'])."' AND c8 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c8'])."' AND c9 = '' ");
                $cnt8 = $rsl8->num_rows;
                while($rw8 = $rsl8->fetch_assoc()){
                    if($cnt8 == 1){
                        echo $rw8['name'];
                    } else {
                        echo $rw8['name'];
                        echo '<br />';
                    }
                }
                echo '</td><td>';
                echo $row['c8'];
                echo '</td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>';
                $rsl9 = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c8 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c8'])."' AND c9 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c9'])."' AND c10 = '' ");
                $cnt9 = $rsl9->num_rows;
                while($rw9 = $rsl9->fetch_assoc()){
                    if($cnt9 == 1){
                        echo $rw9['name'];
                    } else {
                        echo $rw9['name'];
                        echo '<br />';
                    }
                }
                echo '</td><td>';
                echo $row['c9'];
                echo '</td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>';
                $rsl10 = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c9 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c9'])."' AND c10 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c10'])."' ");
                $cnt10 = $rsl10->num_rows;
                while($rw10 = $rsl10->fetch_assoc()){
                    if($cnt10 == 1){
                        echo $rw10['name'];
                    } else {
                        echo $rw10['name'];
                        echo '<br />';
                    }
                }
                echo '</td><td>';
                echo $row['c10'];
                echo '</td></tr></table></div>';
            } else {
                echo '<tr><td>';
                $rsl5 = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE c5 = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row['c5'])."' AND c6 = '' ");
                $cnt5 = $rsl5->num_rows;
                while($rw5 = $rsl5->fetch_assoc()){
                    if($cnt5 == 1){
                        echo $rw5['name'];
                    } else {
                        echo $rw5['name'];
                        echo '<br />';
                    }
                }
                echo '</td><td>';
                echo $row['c5'];
                echo '</td></tr>';
                for ($i=6; $i<=$numcol; $i++) {
                    $rsl = 'rsl' . $i;
                    $rw = 'rw' . $i;
                    $cnt = 'cnt' . $i;
                    $currcln = 'c' . $i;
                    $prevcln = 'c' . ($i - 1);
                    $nextcln = 'c' . ($i + 1);
                    echo '<tr><td>';
                    $rsl = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE ".$prevcln." = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row[$prevcln])."' AND ".$currcln." = '".mysqli_escape_string($conn, $row[$currcln])."' AND ".$nextcln." = '' ");
                    $cnt = $rsl->num_rows;
                    while($rw = $rsl->fetch_assoc()){
                        if($cnt == 1){
                            echo $rw['name'];
                        } else {
                            echo $rw['name'];
                            echo '<br />';
                        }
                    }
                    echo '</td><td>';
                    echo $row[$currcln];
                    echo '</td></tr>';
                }
                echo '</table></div>';
            }

        }
    }
}
?>
```